# Fast Computation of the Divisor Summatory Function $\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{d|i}d$

Tags: number-theory, summation, algorithms, computer-science, divisor-sum

Denote by $\sigma_1(n)$ the sum of the divisors of $n$. For example, when $n=9$ we get $\sigma_1(9) = 1+3+9=13$. Define $D(x) = \sum_{n=1}^x\sigma_1(n)$. Varius methods are known for computing $D(x)$, most rely upon the crucial observation that summing the divisors themselves rather than looking at each number and its divisors specifically, we get a faster computation. That is:
$$D(x) = \sum_{d=1}^x d \cdot \bigg \lfloor \frac xd \bigg \rfloor$$ Simply put, for each divisor, we multiply the divisor by the amount of times it appears. This form addresses an $\mathcal{O}(n)$ computation. But noticing the floor function is constant for large ranges, it admits a faster, $\mathcal{O}(n^{1/2})$ computation: 
$$D(x) = \sum_{d=1}^{ \big\lfloor \frac {x}{\sqrt x+1} \big \rfloor} d \cdot \bigg \lfloor \frac xd \bigg \rfloor + \sum_{d=1}^{\sqrt x} d \cdot \Bigg (T \bigg(\bigg \lfloor \frac nd \bigg \rfloor \bigg ) - T \bigg(\bigg \lfloor \frac n{d+1} \bigg \rfloor \bigg ) \Bigg )$$
where $T(n)= \frac {n\cdot(n+1)}2$ is the $n$'th triangular number. Further simplifaction can result in an algorithm of similiar time complexity, but still noticably faster: 
$$D(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor} \left( k \cdot \left \lfloor {\frac{x}{k}} \right \rfloor  + T \left( \left \lfloor{\frac{x}{k}} \right \rfloor \right) \right) - T(\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor) \cdot \lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor$$

Using the last formula, I can compute the correct result for $D(10^{18})$ in about 3.5 minutes (using Java). However, in https://oeis.org/search?q=87%2C8299&language=english&go=Search , (in the links section) terms up to $D(10^{36})$ are known. Extrapolating how long my algorithm would take, it seems to me that even when using a faster computer and a faster programming language, this would still be unfeasible using the last formula, which is $\mathcal{O}(n^{1/2})$. I would assume an algorithm with a better time complexity was used (my guess would be $\mathcal{O}(n^{1/3})$).

Am I wrong or is there really an even faster algorithm based on a more sophisticated mathematical observation behind it? If there is, I would like to know about it.

Comment: @reuns In the links section, there is a link for values up to $D(10^{36})$ : https://oeis.org/A072692/b072692.txt

Comment: Why are the first digits exactly the same for consecutives values of $D(10^n)$, do you see a faster way to evaluate only the $\bmod 10^m$ part ?

Comment: $D(x)$ has an asymptotic formula. As $x$ approaches infinity, $D(x) \to \frac {x^2 {\pi}^2}{12}$ @reuns

Comment: @reuns It's possible there is a way, although you would need to come up with a precise value for the $n-m$ part. I suspect the asymptotic formula was not used, but rather an accurate calculation, but I really might be wrong

Comment: In the PROG section for A072692 there's a reference to efficient code from A024916; cross-referencing with the PROG section there, the version by M. F. Hasler on 18 April 2015 seems to be what you may be looking for. I don't know PARI, but it appears to run in $\mathcal{O}(n^{1/2})$? PS: I was brought here by [this question on Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/265114/67312); perhaps someone may have some insights from submissions there.

Comment: [this link](https://oeis.org/A072692/a072692.txt) has the original code by P L Patodia, formatted nicely; it does appear to be $\mathcal{O}(n^{1/2})$